# How to avoid duplicate initialization of BeanPostProcessor with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm running into an issue where a `BeanPostProcessor` is initializing more than once. The reason it is doing so is because it's included in `ApplicationContextConfig` and when `ServletContextConfig` scans the code, it initializes another independent version of the `BeanPostProcessor`.

The reason this is an issue is because there should only be one `BeanPostProcessor` per application (this is because if I have more than one, it'll cause a threading issue).

The reason I can't exclude `BeanPostProcessor` from the component scan of `ServletContextConfig` is because there is a class that depends on the `BeanPostProcessor` being there to create the bean.

Any ideas? If it's possible, I'd like to "share" the `ConfigBeanPostProcessor` I created in `WebApplicationContext` with that of `ServletContextConfig`.

WebApplicationInitializer.java

```
public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractServletInitializer 
{
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getApplicationContextConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationContextConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletContextConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServletContextConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{
                new DelegatingFilterProxy(LoggingFilter.FILTER_NAME),
                new DelegatingFilterProxy(MonitoringFilter.FILTER_NAME)
        };
    }
}
```

ApplicationContextConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, excludeFilters = @Filter({Controller.class, Configuration.class}))
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConfigBeanPostProcessor() {
        //return ConfigBeanPostProcessor
    }
}
```

ServletContextConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, includeFilters =             
@ComponentScan.Filter({Controller.class}))
public class ServletContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    @Autowire
    private ClassThatDependsOnConfigPostProcessor class;
}
```

Comment: `BeanPostProcessor` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instances only operate in the context they are created in. They are also not looked up from the parent context like regular beans. Also imho it is strange that you have a class that would depend on an infrastructure component. Also the fact that you get threading issues makes me wonder what you are doing in said `BeanPostProcessor` as it feels like you are doing things you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: So actually, I looked through the code more and it seems that the `ApplicationContextConfig` is being initiated twice for some reason. It appears to be happening for all repos so it seems like it's our company's platform code that is causing this issue.

Comment: There are 2 application contexts, one from the `ContextLoaderListener` and the other from the `DispatcherServlet`. Both your component-scans do almost the same. I suspect in your `ServletContextConfig` you want to add `useDefaultFilters=false` to scan only for `@Controller` annotated classes. An include doesn't automatically disable the defaults.